# how to use regex negation string

Tags: visual-studio, regex, regex-negation

can any body tell me how to use regex for negation of string?
I wanna find all line that start with `public class` and then `any thing except first,second` and finally any thing else.

for example in the result i expect to see `public class base` but not `public class myfirst:base`
can any body help me please??

Comment: What language are you writing in?

Comment: What regex flavor are you using? This is a very terrific resource for learning regexps: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: First, **what language is this for? (JavaScript, PHP, C#, etc.)?**

Second, there is a contradiction in the question posted.  It says you want to find "any thing except first,second", but your example uses `myfirst`!  Which is it?

Finally, is this string multi-line?

Comment: Based on comment to my answer below, it looks like this is **Visual Studio** find dialog, which has it's own non-standard regex syntax.

Comment: i didnt know that has its own regex syntax!

Answer (score 4):

Use a negative lookahead:

```
public\s+class\s+(?!first|second).+
```

Answer (score 3):

If Peter is correct and you're using Visual Studio's `Find` feature, this should work:

```
^:b*public:b+class:b+~(first|second):i.*$
```

`:b` matches a space or tab
`~(...)` is how VS does a negative lookahead
`:i` matches a C/C++ identifier

The rest is standard regex syntax:
`^` for beginning of line
`$` for end of line
`.` for any character
`*` for zero or more
`+` for one or more
`|` for alternation

Comment: For completeness, you should add "`|` for alternation" to your second key.

Comment: Done.  You know, there's actually some good ideas in the VS regex flavor.  It's too bad it's so thoroughly incompatible with every other Perl-derived flavor.

Comment: Yeah, the stuff like `:i` does seem a good idea, but it should really have been implemented in a compatible way, or marked more clearly (e.g. in the drop-down have "Regular expressions (.NET)" and "Regular expressions (VS-style)" or whatever).

Answer (score 1):

Both the other two answers come close, but probably fail for different reasons.

```
public\s+class\s+(?:(?!first|second).)+
```

Note how there is a (non-capturing) group around the negative lookahead, to ensure it applies to more than just the first position.

And that group is less restrictive - since `.` excludes newline, it's using that instead of `\S`, and the `$` is not necessary - this will exclude the specified words and match others.

No slashes wrapping the expression since those aren't required in everything and may confuse people that have only encountered string-based regex use.

*If this still fails, post the exact content that is wrongly matched or missed, and what language/ide you are using.*

**Update:**
Turns out you're using Visual Studio, which has it's own [special regex implementation](http://knol.google.com/k/brian-lalonde/microsoft-visual-studio-special-regular/34l0bem1ht3yo/3#), for some unfathomable reason. So, you'll be wanting to try this instead:

```
public:b+class:b+~(first|second)+$
```

I have no way of testing that - if it doesn't work, try dropping the `$`, but otherwise you'll have to find a VS user. Or better still, the VS engineer(s) responsible for this stupid non-standard regex.

Comment: unforttunatly but it didnt return any thing niether

Comment: i'm using c#.
the result is:
Find all "public\s+class\s+(?:(?!first|second).)+", Subfolders, Find Results 1, "Entire Solution"
  Matching lines: 0    Matching files: 0    Total files searched: 13

Comment: How many of those 13 files match when you search for `public\s+class\s+.+` ?

Comment: Hmmm, it sounds like you're using Visual Studio IDE search, (*not* C# code). The regex implementation in VS is completely screwed up, so that's why these are all failing. I'll update my answer with a VS solution too.

Comment: @ Peter Boughton it didnt return any thing

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that should work for you

```
/public\sclass\s(?:[^fs\s]+|(?!first|second)\S)+(?=\s|$)/
```

The second look a head could be changed to a $(end of line) or another anchor that works for your particular use case, like maybe a '{'

Edit: Try changing the last part to:

```
(?=\s|$)
```